# Disable alternative methods in Paypal (Austria)

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I am trying to disable alternative payments method in Austria when a user is paying via PayPal.

[image]

I have already declared in script disable funding

```
const loadPaypal = (callback) => {
        const existingScript = document.getElementById('paypalsdk');

        if (!existingScript) {
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=XXXXX&currency=EUR&disable-funding=credit,card,bancontact&buyer-country=AT';
            // script.async = true;
            script.id = 'paypalsdk'; // e.g., googleMaps or stripe
            document.body.appendChild(script);

            script.onload = () => {
                if (callback) callback();
            };
        }

        if (existingScript && callback) callback();
    };
```

but alternative methods are still showing. Anyone idea how to remove alternative methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which payment methods you want to disable.

Judging by your screenshot, you need to manually append the `sofort` and `eps` to the script.src params, like this:

```
script.src = 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=XXXXX&currency=EUR&disable-funding=credit,card,bancontact,sofort,eps&buyer-country=AT';
```

You can check out additional parameters in the disable funding section of the official Paypal [documentation](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20script.src%20=%20%27https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=XXXXX&currency=EUR&disable-funding=credit,card,bancontact&buyer-country=AT%27;)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate methods are shown according to the buyer's detected location (simulatable in sandbox using [buyer-country](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/#buyer-country)), so the Austrian methods will only be shown to buyers detected as being in Austria, while **other methods will be shown to buyers in other countries**. This is generally desirable behavior, and disabling a few particular methods is usually not a useful general solution.

When space is a concern, consider a [horizontal layout](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/horizontal)